# Multiple query are not inserting data Wordpress

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

I wrote a function where two insert query have. One is executed and inserting data properly. But next one is not executing. And I cant check the value i want to insert if it is set or not. How to do the stuff? EXPERT's have a look kindly. My function is given below:

```
add_action( 'save_post', 'cs_product_save' );

   function cs_product_save( $post_id ){

        global $wpdb;

        $cs_product_array = $_POST['cs_product'];
        $cs_product_count = count($cs_product_array);

        $event_start_date = $_POST['event_start_date'];
        $event_end_date = $_POST['event_end_date'];
        $event_start_time = $_POST['event_start_time'];
        $event_end_time = $_POST['event_end_time'];
        $event_all_day = $_POST['event_all_day'];
        $event_phone = $_POST['event_phone'];
        $event_location = $_POST['event_location'];
        $event_map = $_POST['event_map'];

        $table_cause_product = "wp_cause_woocommerce_product";

        $table_event_info = "wp_cause_info";

        for( $i=0; $i < $cs_product_count; $i++ ){
          $wpdb->insert($table_cause_product,array(
            'cause_ID'=>$post_id,
            'product_ID'=>$cs_product_array[$i],
            'status'=>'1'
          ),array('%d','%d','%d'));
        }

         $wpdb->insert($table_event_info,array(
             'cause_ID'=>$post_id,
             'event_start_date'=>$event_start_date,
             'event_end_date'=>$event_end_date,
             'event_start_time'=>$event_start_time,
             'event_end_time'=>$event_end_time,
             'event_all_day'=>$event_all_day,
             'event_phone'=>$event_phone,
             'event_location'=>$event_location,
             'event_map'=>$event_map
           ),array('%d','%s','%s','%s','%s','%d','%s','%s','%d'));
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't see any problem here with your code. But be sure to double check your code.

The issues my be with the name of your database table names. Are you sure that `$table_cause_product` and `$table_event_info` holds the actual name of the tables? I would recommend to use `$wpdb->prefix` instead of harcoding table names.

In my case I would check the function in several parts.

1. Check the `$_POST` actually holds the data I want.
2. Use `$result = $wpdb->insert( $table, $data, $format );` in all cases for debug purpose as the `$result` would hold the result of the operation. If its is `false` then I would be sure that there is definitely something wrong with the operation.
3. Finally I would use a `wp_die()` (though its not a standard way to do, but it suffices my purpose) so that I can see the dumped variable data.

One major issue you might face with your code that if the post is edited after saving then it might insert another row for same post data. Again if the post is being autosaved, you need some safeguard. I would recommend a where clause here to check the row already exists or not. If exists then you can simply update the row, or else insert the data.

Hope this might help you.

Comment: thats great. But can you edit your post with some more insight about the problem in your code and how you solved it, for future reference?

Comment: Yes actually I wrote the same function some days ago which i forgot :P and I rewrite the function again. Previous one was working .. that's why new one had not been executed. When I got to previous one and put my stuffs in there and remove the new one it became successful. It was not very important to post here .. that's why i didn't post it. Bt thanks a lot @maksbd19